# Classic ASP FormatNumber Making Number 0.0

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to get a decimal value 2 places past the decimal...

I am looking to get the average of some numbers, and then display them in a table..

Here is my code and then my output

```
<% response.write(rsTemp("8over") & "<BR>") %>
<% response.write(rsTemp5("qty") & "<BR>") %>

<% PercentageOver = rsTemp("8over")/rsTemp5("qty")%>

<% response.write(PercentageOver & "<BR>") %>

<% PercentageOver = FormatNumber(PercentageOver,2) %>

<% response.write(PercentageOver) %>
```

Output:

```
2
618
3.23624595469256E-03
0.00
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried all kinds of things like CDbl etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number is `E-03` (×10<sup>-3</sup>) so there are no non-zero digits in the first 3 digits.

```
?FormatNumber(PercentageOver, 3)
0.003
```

Comment: Good catch with the `E-03`.

Answer (score 1):

First off make sure that you are working with decimal and integer values

```
<%
Dim eightover, qty, PercentageOver 

eightover = CDbl(rsTemp("8over"))
qty = CLng(rsTemp("qty"))

PercentageOver = CDbl(eightover / qty)
Response.Write FormatNumber(PercentageOver, 2)
%>
```

Remember if you are going to use `FormatNumber()` you are in effect creating a string representation of the number. Never use a value that has been modified with `FormatNumber()` to do calculations.